# Printing external file on Google Chrome and Firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome, printing

Trying to print an external HTML file using javascript.  The code works in IE.  However, in Google Chrome and Mozilla FireFox, it does not print the external page, it prints the current page.  Any suggestions?

**Header Code**

```
<link rel="alternate" media="print" href="file.htm" />
```

**Body Code**

```
<a href="file.htm" onclick="window.print(); return false;">Print Agreement</a>
```

Google Chrome loads its "chrome://print/" for print preview, maybe causing this issue. 
Is there another way of doing this?  So far the only workaround I can get is to open a popup and have the user print from there... But it's an extra step that seems pointless, and no one likes pop-ups anymore.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to give users option to view first the Agreement, not directly print it.
And, if you do so, you can invoke printing from the Agreement itself, with a button for example, it can be also a link, using simple HTML/JavaScript code:

`<input name="print" type="button" id="print" value="Print agreement" onclick="window.print();"/>`

I personally use this approach and works even with IE5.5.